# Grub installing in wrong drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd, grub

I have two drives one ssd and one hdd in my hp laptop, windows 10 is installed on the ssd, I have been trying to install linux mint in the free space in the hdd. 
I have been using this as a guide:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives

Even after following the guide the grub keeps installing in the ssd in the windows boot manager partition. When I select the boot loader from ssd it enters the GRUB Command line. In the command line I tried to list the available disk images but it shows no bootable images, I get 5 entries, namely, (hd0), (hd0,gpt1)...(hd0,gpt4). Out of these (hd0, gpt2) is the only one on which ls works others show unknown filesystem.

How do I get Grub to install in the EFI partition created in the HDD and not the windows boot partition?

Comment: *grub keeps installing in the ssd in the windows boot manager partition* Do you mean a partition named EFI? That's exactly where it should be installed and that partition is as much Windows as is for any other OS. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Yes but then it isnt able to find any operating systems. That is why I created a second EFI partition in the HDD(where linux is to be installed).

Comment: Please read the link posted in the previous comment. You really need to understand how UEFI works and what settings (and where) you need to change at the UEFI firmware itself. No need for a second EFI partition - and doing this you showed you don't understand yet the basics.

Comment: This answer is also useful and explains everything the users need to know: https://superuser.com/questions/1354339/changing-boot-mode-from-uefi-to-legacy Don't forget to read my comment as well.